# Screen problem while booting Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I need help. I updated Nvidia drivers on my PC and also I installed the CUDA toolkit (I have no idea if this is important, since I'm pretty new to all this). At first everything was fine. But next day I experienced screen problems while booting the system. The screen becomes "smeared" and unstable. I could say I recognize every stage of turning on based on colors, but no letters are readable and no picture is recognizible. After it's completely awake, the screen is normal.[The image of a screen while booting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wunar.jpg)

I tried to resolve this by changing to different drivers, but nothing helped. In some instances it was worse.

This is my current configuration:
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.
When running `Isb_release -a` I also get a message:

> No LSB modules are available.

I'm using Nvidia GeForce RTX 3090 GPU. The driver version is 535.86.10, and CUDA version is 12.2.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem and the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need cuda and should install your NVIDIA driver as I mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1468623/906933) using the "Hardware" App from Ubuntu.

This said, others had that problem as well and have been [answered here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1291788/906933). It seems you'll need the NVIDIA drivers 455 - your best bet would be to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04, which has the latest drivers for your Nvidia card.

The essence of both links is, that you shouldn't "download" any driver from "somewhere" but use the inbuild driver mechanism of Ubuntu (or a trusthworthy ppa), since the drivers have to be compiled against your kernel (Ubuntus drivers are correctly build)

Last thing: NVIDIA doesn't play nice with Wayland (the default UI Session in Ubuntu 22.04), so you'd be advised to change your session (during login) to a X11Session